# Homework Assignment, Java Method using an Array

Tags: java, arrays

first time posting here, I have this problem:

Write a static method named mostBowlsFull, to be added to the Bowl class, which is passed an array of Bowl objects, and returns true if a strict majority of the Bowls in the array are not empty. Thus if the array consists of 11 bowls and 6 are not empty, your method should return true, but if the array consists of 12 bowls and 6 (or fewer) are not empty, your method should return false.

we are given the class here:

https://cesd12.cs.umass.edu/owlj/servlet/ContentFileServer?ID=10778&ManuallyGraded=0&SecureID=2084635103&Server=owl-ijava31haverhillhs&TsActn=1422069785&datasrc=OwliJava31HaverhillHS&fileRequestID=4147

Not sure if it is accessible or if you must be logged on to the service :/

Anyways, this is the code I have

```
`public static boolean mostBowlsFull(Bowl bowls[]){
  int count = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < bowls[].length(), j++){
    if(bowls[j].getEmpty == true){
      count++;
    }
  }
  if(count > (bowls[].length()/2)){
    return true;
  }
}`
```

I am getting for feedback:

The system has detected compilation errors. This could be caused by:
Missing semicolon ; at the end of a statement.
Unclosed braces {}.
Unclosed parentheses ().
Unterminated string literals "".
Invalid method signature.
Missing return statement.
Redeclared variable or data member.
etc.

Any noticeable errors?

EDIT: Alright, so after review I have

```
public static boolean mostBowlsFull(Bowl bowls[]){
  int count = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < bowls.length; j++){
    if(bowls[j].getEmpty() == true){
      count++;
    }
  }
  if(count > (bowl.length/2)){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Still receiving the same message, although I do understand everything that was pointed out, thank you.

Comment: there is "" character in code, change }` to }. same with before public keyword. remove it. change `,` to `;` in for loop. `for(int j = 0; j < bowls[].length();j++)`

Comment: I think that's just formatting;  inline combined with code format

Comment: Look at your for loop.

Comment: `bowls[j].getEmpty()`

Comment: Don't you need to return false in the updated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier and less time taking for you to use an IDE and resolve compilation errors.
I see two errors in  your for loop:

```
  for(int j = 0; j < bowls[].length(), j++){
```

use of comma instead of semicolon.  `for` loop syntax is

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Also length is a property for arrays and not a method. So use `bowls.length` instead of `bowls[].length`. Also not that you don't need `[]` while using `length`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the length of `bowls`, use `bowls.length`, not `bowls[].length()`.

Also, in your for loop you need a semi-colon in between all three statements:

```
for(int j = 0; j < bowls.length; j++){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean mostBowlsFull(Bowl bowls[]){
      int count = 0;
      boolean ret=false;
      for(int j = 0; j < bowls.length; j++){
        if(bowls[j].getEmpty() == false){
          count++;
        }
      }
      if(count > (bowls.length/2)){
        ret=true;
      }
      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Usually we do not complete homework of people seeking to get that work done here, but this looks ok :-)